# NServiceBus Visual Studio Solution Architecture

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus, esb

Just started with NServiceBus and I am trying to understand how the bus fits into my VS solution.

Let's assume an existing application, that has an ASP.Net front end and a BLL.  I am using Windsor for DI and my BLL has no knowledge of the container.  I wire the container up in a separate project I call "MyNamespace.IOC", and only this project and my web project have knowledge of Windsor.

I need access to the bus in my BLL (since that is where I will be sending/publishing/handling messages).  I need to configure NSB using Windsor, and (I think) pass an instance of my container to the Configure.With().CastleWindorBuilder() method at app startup.

It seems odd to have all three projects have reference to the NSB DLLs.  How does one normally wire this all together?

Comment: NSB usually serves as infrastructure and is orthogonal to a lot of the other stuff in your project. What are you using NSB for? What are the benefits you think you'll be getting from NSB? Following @rarous advice, you can abstract the bus behind an interface. Maybe have a look at the concept of onion architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to reference NSB in your BLL / domain layer you could have a look at 'domain events'.  The domain event handlers can sit in their own implementation layer leaving your domain ignorant of the handling of the events and, therefore, requiring no knowledge of the service bus.  From there you could publish your esb messages.  It may not seem like much of a difference but the domain event-handling layer is more isolated from the domain.

Just as a side-note: since you are starting out with a service bus you could also have a look at my FOSS project over at http://shuttle.codeplex.com/ --- any feedback would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract bus behind some interface and provide the implementation only in IoC and Web projects.